# openpyxl removes drop-down lists

Tags: python, openpyxl

I wrote a Python script, which inserts data into an Excel file. My problem is that my drop-down list disappears after every save. I do have multiple sheets in my Excel file and not only my current page, which I edit is affected, also all others too.

Here is my code:

```
def openExcelFile(path: str = None) -> openpyxl:
    if path is None:
        raise ValueError("path is None!")

    return openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

def saveToExcelFile(wb_object: openpyxl = None, path: str = None) -> None:
    if wb_object is None or path is None:
        raise ValueError("wb_object or path is None!")

    wb_object.save(path)
    wb_object.close()

def findDuplicate(sheet_object, dataset: LandRegister = None, column: int = 0, row: int = 0, index: int = 0):
    if index == 0 and row == 1:
        return (-1, -1, -1)

    duplicate_found = False
    family_found = False

    for i in range(0, index + 1):
        cell_firstname = sheet_object.cell(row=row - i, column=column).value
        cell_lastname = sheet_object.cell(row=row - i, column=column + 1).value
        cell_address = sheet_object.cell(row=row - i, column=column + 2).value
        cell_zipcode = sheet_object.cell(row=row - i, column=column + 3).value

        if cell_lastname == dataset.lastname[index] and \
                cell_address == dataset.address[index] and \
                cell_zipcode == dataset.zipcode[index]:
            if cell_firstname == dataset.firstname[index]:
                return (-2, -2, -2)
            return (row - 1, column, index)

    if duplicate_found:
        return (-2, -2, -2)
    elif family_found:
        return (row - 1, column, index)
    else:
        return (-1, -1, -1)

def insertNewRow(sheet, row, nr):
    sheet.insert_rows(row, amount=1)
    cell_object = sheet.cell(
        row=row, column=2)
    cell_object.value = nr

def insertData(sheet_object, dataset: LandRegister = None, column: int = 0, row: int = 0, index: int = 0):
    # Insert the first name.
    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column)
    cell_object.value = dataset.firstname[index]

    # Insert the last name.
    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column + 1)
    cell_object.value = dataset.lastname[index]

    # Insert the location
    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column + 2)
    cell_object.value = dataset.address[index]

    # Insert the zipcode
    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column + 3)
    tmp_zipcode = dataset.zipcode[index]
    cell_object.value = tmp_zipcode

def insertMetaData(sheet_object, row: int = 0, column: int = 0):
    kg_nr_p = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column)
    kg_name_p = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column + 1)
    grst_nr_p = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row, column=column + 2)
    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row+1, column=column)
    cell_object.value = kg_nr_p.value

    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row+1, column=column + 1)
    cell_object.value = kg_name_p.value

    cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
        row=row+1, column=column + 2)
    cell_object.value = grst_nr_p.value

def writeToExcelFile(wb_object, dataset: LandRegister = None, sheet_name: str = None, cell: str = 'A0'):
    if dataset is None or sheet_name is None or wb_object is None:
        raise ValueError("dataset, sheet_name or wb_object is None!")

    start_row = SETTINGS[sheet_name]['row']
    start_col = SETTINGS[sheet_name]['col']

    sheet_names = wb_object.sheetnames

    if sheet_name not in sheet_names:
        raise ValueError("No matching sheet name found!")

    sheet_object = wb_object[sheet_name]
    row = 0

    for index in range(len(dataset.firstname)):

        found_row, found_colum, found_index = findDuplicate(
            sheet_object, dataset, column=start_col, row=(row + start_row), index=index)

        if found_colum == -1 and found_row == -1 and found_index == -1:
            if index > 0:
                cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
                    row=row + start_row-1, column=start_col-10)
                insertNewRow(sheet_object, row + start_row, cell_object.value)
                insertMetaData(sheet_object, row + start_row-1, start_col-9)

            insertData(sheet_object, dataset,
                       column=start_col, row=(row + start_row), index=index)
            row += 1
        elif found_colum == -2 and found_row == -2 and found_index == -2:
            continue
        else:
            cell_object = sheet_object.cell(
                row=found_row, column=found_colum)
            cell_object.value += " und " + dataset.firstname[index]

    SETTINGS[sheet_name]['row'] = start_row + row

def loadSettings():
    global SETTINGS

    with open(os.path.join(DIRPATH, 'settings.json'), 'r') as file:
        SETTINGS = json.load(file)

def saveSettings():
    with open(os.path.join(DIRPATH, 'settings.json'), 'w') as file:
        json.dump(SETTINGS, file)

def run(files: List[str], landregiser: LandRegister = None, extractor: ExtractorLandRegister = None) -> None:
    path = os.path.join(DIRPATH, EXCEL_FILE_NAME)
    excel_file = openExcelFile(path)
    sheet_name = SETTINGS["Sheets"][SETTINGS["Source"]['4']]

    main_logger.info(f'Insert in {sheet_name}')

    counter = 1
    for key in files:
        print_message = f'==={files[key]:<2}===\n'
        try:
            txt = extractor.extractTextFromPdf(files[key])

            landregiser.dataset = txt

            landregiser.execute()

            writeToExcelFile(excel_file, landregiser, sheet_name)
            main_logger.info(
                f'Counter {counter:<2}: | {files[key]:<75} | {len(landregiser.firstname):<2}')
            counter += 1
        except Exception as exce:
            print(exce)
            print_message += str(exce)
            main_logger.error("Error")
            counter += 1
            SETTINGS[sheet_name]['row'] = SETTINGS[sheet_name]['row'] + 1

    saveToExcelFile(excel_file, path)
    # saveSettings()

def main():
    loadSettings()
    ex = ExtractorLandRegister(SETTINGS["Source"]['4'])
    lr = LandRegister()

    files = ex.getPdfFiles()

    run(files, landregiser=lr, extractor=ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do I use openpyxl in a wrong way or does it not support to load an existing drop-down list?

Comment: Your dropdowns in Excel are Data Validations, yea? Here is the openpyxl doc on those: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html. You may be able to get what you want by including data validation code in your script here.

Comment: On the [simple usage](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) page of the docs there is a note saying *"openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name."* Maybe drop-down lists are also a part of that...

Comment: It's most likely that the filters contain some extensions beyond the OOXML specification and these are not supported. You should see a warning in this case.

Comment: @Tomerikoo probably need to update that remark. Charts and images are supported and drawing support is getting better.

Comment: @scotscotmcc I included it, but nothing has changes... It still disappears. Also tried to save it via another name

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is not working to load the Data-Validation into, but it is possible to insert the data and afterwards format everything accordingly.

To make a validation with openpyxl use this [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html) to do so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).